# Drop Down list in yii.?

Tags: php, yii

I am facing hard times working with yii framework,The latest I ecounterd is while populating data from database in a drop down.i have tried few things including codes from the site,but no use,I have the following codes,Have a model named as PostJob.PHP.

Do i have to write a seprate function in model.?

view: postjob.php

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Category'); ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('category', $model->title, $list, array('empty' => '(Select a Category')); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'category'); ?>
</div>
```

and in view section , I have given :

```
<?php
   $list = CHtml::listData(PostJob::model()->findAll(array('jobpost','description')),'id','title');
?>
```

geting nothing.Pls Help.

Comment: PostJob::model()->findAll(array('jobpost','description')) - why you pass this array as condition to findAll method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this:

```
<?php $list = CHtml::listData(PostJob::model()->findAll(),'id','title'); ?>
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Category'); ?>
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model , 'category', $list, array('empty' => '(Select a Category')); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model,'category'); ?>
```

Comment: Its throwing error  "Object of class PostJob could not be converted to string":\

Comment: on which line it's throwing?

Comment: <?php echo CHtml::dropDownList($model,'category',$list,array('empty' =>'(Select a Category')); ?>

Comment: in my code I wrote `$form->dropDownList(` , not **CHtml** !